# to insert array values into specific table cells/columns

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I'm creating a function that should take the data from an array (results) and put them into specific columns of the table. The array is divided with numbers that identify the column in which the following data should be entered.

Eg:

```
var results = [1, 'aaaaaa', 'bbb',2, 'ccc', 3, 'dddd', 'eeee', 4, 'fff'];

col 1: 'aaaaaa', 'bbb';
col 2: 'ccc'; etc.
```

I've tried it in many ways and I can not get it to work.

At the moment the code looks like this. I'm no sure how to do it:

```
var results = [1, 'aaaaaa','bbb',2, 'ccc', 3, 'dddd', 'eeee', 4, 'fff'];
var k = 0;
function populateTable(table, rows, cells, content) {
    if (!table) table = document.createElement('table');
    for (var i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        for (var j = 0; j < cells; ++j) {
            row.appendChild(document.createElement('td'));
            if (i > 0 && j == 0) {
                row.cells[j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(content + 'PN'));
            }
            else if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
                row.cells[j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(content + 'TYPE'));
            }
            else if (j > 0 && i == 0) {
                row.cells[j].appendChild(document.createTextNode(content + 'LABLE ' + j));
            }

            else if (j > 0 && i > 0 && results[i] != k) {
                    row.cells[k].appendChild(document.createTextNode(content + results[i]));

            }
        }
        table.appendChild(row);
        k++;
    }
    return table;
}

function load() {
    document.getElementById('tablearea')
        .appendChild(populateTable(null, 9, 10, ""));
}
```

Comment: The data format of you `results` array is awful and is why this is harder than is should be. Do you have control over that?

Comment: Yes. What is the  best  format?

Comment: I would consider either an object pointing to arrays : `{1: ['aaaaaa', 'bbb']}`, or an array of arrays `[['aaaaaa', 'bbb'], ['ccc'], ['dddd', 'eeee'], ['fff']]` Then you don't have to scan through to find the column number — the index *is* the column. Of course, its even better if you can put the data in rows.

Comment: Thanks Mark_M. I'm going to try this way. =D.

Answer (score 0):

First format the results into something like:

```
{
  1: ['aaaaaa', 'bbb'],
  2: ['ccc'],
  3: ['dddd', 'eeee'],
  4: ['fff']
}
```

Then generate the table:

```js
const results = [1, 'aaaaaa', 'bbb',2, 'ccc', 3, 'dddd', 'eeee', 4, 'fff', 5, 'ggg', 'hhhh', 'iiii'];

// First format the results

const formattedResults = {};
let columnIndex = 0;

results.forEach(elt => {
  if (!isNaN(elt)) {
    formattedResults[elt] = [];
    columnIndex = elt;
  } else {
    formattedResults[columnIndex].push(elt);
  }
});

// Then generate the table
const table = document.createElement('table');

const columnKeys = Object.keys(formattedResults);
const maxRows = Math.max(...columnKeys.map(key => formattedResults[key].length));

for (let i = 0; i < maxRows; i = i + 1) {
  const tr = document.createElement('tr');
  
  columnKeys.forEach(colKey => {
    const td = document.createElement('td');
    
    if (formattedResults[colKey][i] !== undefined) {
      td.textContent = formattedResults[colKey][i];
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
  });
  
  table.appendChild(tr);
}

document.getElementById('tableArea').appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="tableArea"></div>
```